# The curve with minimum max slope with a given area under it

Tags: integration, derivatives

How to prove that from all the curves like $y=f(x)$, $x \in [0,s]$ where $\int_0^sf(x)=A$, the curve in the picture below has the smallest slope?

Edit: The function also is subject to $f(0)=f(s)=0$, and is continuous.

Any other curve satisfying $\int_0^sf(x)=A$, will have a $max(|f'(x)|)$ greater than $\frac{4A}{s^2}$.

[image]

The function in the picture is:
$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{4A}{s^2} \times x,  &    x \in [0,\frac{s}{2}] \\
\frac{4A}{s} \times (1-  \frac{x}{s}), & x \in [\frac{s}{2},s]
\end{cases}
$

What the picture shows (the vertical axis) can be the velocity of a vehicle. The area under the curve is the distance that it travels. The slope of the curve is the acceleration and deceleration of the vehicle. The horizontal axis is time.

What I am trying to prove is that if a vehicle is supposed to travel a given distance in a given time, using bang-bang control method, i.e. applying constant acceleration and constant deceleration equal to the acceleration will require the minimum torque from the vehicle.

Anything other than bang-bang control, will require a higher torque rating for the vehicle.

Comment: I assume that $f$ must also fulfill $f(0)=f(s)=0$, that it must be continuous and that it has only a countable (or finite?) number of $x$s where $f'(x)$ does not exist?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Any other curve will have a smaller slope at some point and a larger slope at some other point to make up for that. So the max slope will be larger. I am looking for a formal proof.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to replace the concept of "slope" with the concept of Lipschitz continuity? Currently you show a non-differentiable function on the one hand, but on the other hand you use $f'$ and you want to have $\max |f'(x)|$ as small as possible. With Lipschitz continuity, this conflict could be resolved. The statement would become "Any other curve satisfying $\int f(x)dx = A$ will have a Lipschitz constant greater than $\frac{4A}{s^2}.$"

Comment: Yes I think it is acceptable. As explained in the edited question I am trying to prove that if a vehicle is supposed to travel a given distance at a given time, bang-bang control method will need the smallest amount of maximum torque from the engine of the vehicle.

Comment: " ..and constant deceleration..", but you are actually applying  an infinite deceleration pulse at $s/2$ ! so minimum torque but the brakes are gone.  I think you have better to remain in the theoretical field and leave out the engineering analogy.

Comment: There is no problem in changing from constant acceleration to constant deceleration instantaneously. Velocity cannot change instantaneously ($f$ must be continuous), but acceleration can attain any values ($f'$ does not have to be continuous.) The *force* that accelerates or decelerates the vehicle does not have to be increased and decreased carefully, it can be - in manner of speaking - switched on and switched off.

Answer (score 0):

Under the conditions $f(0)=f(s)=0$ and $f$ is continuous, it is obvious that each continuous curve that has points inside the shown triangle, but does not have points above the triangle, will result in a smaller $A$ (monotonicity of the integral). Therefore, each curve with the same $A$ but *not* identical to the given one must have points above the triangle. You can then use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to prove that there must be an $x$ with a larger absolute slope than $4A/s^2.$

In order to prove the first part formally, I show that the following holds for continuous functions $f$ and $g$:
$$
g(t)\geq f(t)\forall t\in[0,s] \; \wedge \; \exists t_0\in(0,s): g(t_0)>f(t_0)
\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;
\int_0^s g(x)dx > \int_0^s f(x)dx
$$

Let $g(t_0) > f(t_0)$ for a given $t_0\in(0,s)$. Let $g(t) \geq f(t)$ for all $t\in[0,s]$.

We set $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}(g(t_0) - f(t_0)).$
As $g-f$ is continuous, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $(t_0-\delta , t_0+\delta) \subset (0,s)$ and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
|t-t_0| < \delta & \Longrightarrow & |(g(t_0)-f(t_0))-(g(t)-f(t))| < \varepsilon \\
  & \Longrightarrow & (g(t_0)-f(t_0))-(g(t)-f(t)) < \varepsilon \\
  & \Longrightarrow & 2\varepsilon-(g(t)-f(t)) < \varepsilon \\
  & \Longrightarrow & \varepsilon < g(t)-f(t)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we look at the integrals
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^s g(x)dx & = & \int_0^{t_0-\delta} g(x)dx +\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} g(x)dx + \int_{t_0+\delta}^s g(x)dx  \\
& \geq & \int_0^{t_0-\delta} f(x)dx +\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} (g(x)-f(x)+f(x))dx + \int_{t_0+\delta}^s f(x)dx  \\
& = & \int_0^{t_0-\delta} f(x)dx +\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} (g(x)-f(x))dx 
+\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta}f(x)dx + \int_{t_0+\delta}^s f(x)dx \\
& \geq & \int_0^{t_0-\delta} f(x)dx +\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} \varepsilon dx 
+\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta}f(x)dx + \int_{t_0+\delta}^s f(x)dx \\
& = & \int_0^s f(x)dx +\int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} \varepsilon dx \\
& = & \int_0^s f(x)dx +2\delta\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Is there an algebraic proof? Or a proof using calculus of variations?

Comment: This is a lot more 'hand-waving' than a formal proof, which was requested. Also, what seems "obvious" to you seems to me false.

Comment: @uniquesolution A question starting with "How to prove" is not necessarily a request for a complete formal proof. I wanted to give some advice how such a proof can be organized. Hints are usually acceptable answers on SE (and are usually not downvoted). They encourage the OP to try a little bit more on their own. If this does not result in any success, they still can ask another question and request more clarification.

Comment: The OP asked for a formal proof in the comments

Comment: @uniquesolution Is my answer to the original question less valuable just because I have not answered the question in the comments, yet? Whether or not the question in the comments is answered should not have any impact on the assessment of the answer to the original question. Maybe I will provide a more detailed proof when I have more time for it.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a proof to support the "fuzzy" part of my original proof sketch.